# Сохранить файл без вывода окна диалога

Tags: c#, wpf

Необходимо сделать что бы файл сохранялся без вывода окна диалога сохранения с одним именем и расширением в одной и той же папке. Сейчас работает так.

```
try
{
    TextRange conversionText = ConversionText;
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        conversionText.Save(stream, System.Windows.DataFormats.Rtf);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            IRtfDocument rtfDocument = RtfInterpreterTool.BuildDoc(reader);
            RtfHtmlConverter htmlConverter = new RtfHtmlConverter(rtfDocument);
            textBox.Text = htmlConverter.Convert();
        }
        System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog save = new System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog();
        if (save.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(save.FileName))
            {
                sw.Write(textBox.Text);

            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(this, "Error " + exception.Message, Title, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
}
```

Comment: А в чем вопрос? Используйте свой filename где-нибудь в домашнем каталоге пользователя, аналогичной /home/user .

Comment: чёт я не понял как то так что ли FileName = @"Z:/Files/Core/Help/help.html"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё разобрался нужно было просто сделать так

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"Z:\Files\Core\Help\Help.html"))
                        {
                            sw.Write(textBox.Text);

                        }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog save = new System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog();
if (save.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(save.FileName))
```

Вы создаете диалоговое окно и потом его открываете `save.ShowDialog()`, и это диалоговое окно будет активно, пока его не закроете. Затем, создавая стрим, Вы используете результат выбора в диалоговом окне выбора файла.

Вам необходимо убрать диалоговое окно и использовать переменную `FileName` с нужным Вам путем.